# ClamAV in Linux

Tags: cpu, gpu, clamav

I have idea to use ClamAV in GPU. There are papers related to it. But I need to know is there any implementations regarding this? Will it work out?

If it is existing already, how to install it such that ClamAV could run in GPU?

There are posts regarding this. But not more useful. Any ideas or suggestions regarding this will be very useful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can see you have asked in many parts of the internet and have got poor reception. To clarify, are you wanting to virus scan your GPU, or are you wanting to use the GPU processor to conduct the virus scan instead of the CPU?

Comment: To use the GPU processor to conduct the virus scan instead of the CPU @Lister

Comment: Not like poor reception. Many people doesn't know it. Thats the reason

Comment: To answer your question, there appears to be no implementation on the developers website nor github https://www.clamav.net/documents/miscellaneous-faq. The article you most likely read (http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch35.html) is a whitepaper made by nvidia developers, they coded their own implementation, you would need to do the same. Kaspersky were working on an implementation but appear to have quietly dropped it. (Last document refering to it was back in 2009)

Comment: ok thank u. Will it be feasible to work over its gpu implementation? This question rises becauses Kaspersky has dropped it

Comment: And nvidia has also made white paper only. Is there any sign for their implementation of it now?

Comment: I cant comment as authority on the matter, there is a link to some people discussing the theory http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/gpu-accelerated-antivirus.339417/ . The nvidia developers were only interested in the possibility, it is up to anti virus companies to actually implement the process. The implementations on a Nvidia and AMD GPU are different, even in standards like open OpenCL drivers behave differently. AV companies would have to work with that issue. Is it possible? Appears so, will companies put the money in? It appears for now no

Comment: I see that this question is interesting from a academic point of few. But of what use would it be? Just asking out of interest.

Comment: For large virus databases, it would be efficient if we offload some initial processing to GPU. Then the meta matching could be done in CPU @paradoxon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer summarizes the current situation for using GPU's instead of the CPU for anti virus scanning.

Nvidia engineers as part of a larger document created a [white paper](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch35.html) on the possibility of using the GPU to perform an AV scan, using an open source anti virus. This paper was published in 2007.

Kaspersky then released a [claim](http://www.geek.com/news/kapersky-labs-releases-gpu-anti-virus-that-runs-360x-faster-than-on-core-2-duo-cpu-1019451/) that their software ran faster on a nvidia card in 2009.

Since then it has been quiet. Presumably anti virus developers have decided the implementation is either impractical or too expensive at this stage in time. I could not say for sure if it will remain this way, I can however say there is currently no consumer implementation of offloading anti-virus processing to the GPU.

Comment: In that white paper, they have mentioned ClamAV. It seems they have worked on it and implemented it. But in this link http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/gpu-accelerated-antivirus.339417/ it has been told that "hard to implement in GPU (or would be slow). So you may have a massive GPU power on your machine, but it wouldn't really help with antivirus scanning - even if the scanner had a GPU implementation".

Comment: what does it mean, whether gpu implementation of clamav is not that much tricky or kaspersky is different from clamav?

Comment: What you have to remember is that every PC is different. the nvidia devs built using their own hardware and chose a software they could manipulate (Open source.) Anti virus companies would need to make the software work on both nvidia & AMD cards, as well as potentially intel's built in chips. That leads us back to the time and money problem.

Comment: Okay as a client side antivirus, gpu implementation fails. But for mail server checks, like while uploading and downloading files gmail is checking for viruses. In this use case, gpu implementation of antivirus can work right?

Comment: The white paper shows that it can work, client and server side. The key is as with any project is it A) worth the money B) worth the time C) will it earn us money D) Is the GPU implementation improvement over CPU worth spending time and money on it?

Comment: okay. in the particular use case (mail), as of now can gpu perform well than cpu or not? (in terms of the factors like money, time, etc)

Comment: I cannot say either way, I do not work in the field. What I can tell you is that no one has deamed it to be important enough to be implemented.

Comment: Exactly. But Kaspersky is a commercial one. ClamAV is an open source one. Kaspersky is more worthy in scanning as it is having powerful layers of scanning engine. But ClamAV is very simple. It is not having more complex implementations as Kaspersky. Thats why the question arises like, why cant ClamAV? Because as it is not complex as Kaspersky, it may not be hard to implement in GPU. In that way, I had thoughts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43457/discussion-between-lister-and-vanns).